# simplexml_load_file: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed

Tags: php, xml, rss

I am trying to display rss feeds for this link. http://vuconnect.com/controls/cms_v2/components/rss/rss.aspx?sid=1643&gid=2&calcid=664&page_id=13
But it is showing this error

> Warning:
>   simplexml_load_file(http://vuconnect.com/controls/cms_v2/components/rss/rss.aspx?sid=1643&gid=2&calcid=664&page_id=13):
>   failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! in
>   G:\wamp\www\scripts\rss_feeds\demo-1.php on line 48

Here is the code i am using.

```
$url = 'http://vuconnect.com/controls/cms_v2/components/rss/rss.aspx?sid=1643&gid=2&calcid=664&page_id=13';
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);       


echo '<pre>';
print_r($xml->channel);
die;

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

needs `allow_url_fopen` to be On.
Check you php.ini and change it to On, if it is Off.

I hope this solves your problem